How do you trigger table formation in MySQL from nodejs using mysql2 driver just like done by sequelize.sync() method
I have created four table models in my node Models folder. Now I want that these tables should be formed whenever I start server just as done by sequelize.sync() method, but I am not using sequelize only mysql2. Do I need to write some code in my main index js file because as such all the tables are not getting formed
I tried creating all tables in one file but that also didn't work. One more thing I am creating associations between tables does that requires some order of forming tables

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to know how do I create tables through nodejs mysql2 only, in database as done by sequelize.sync() method. I have created tables in models folder what code should I write in my main server.js file to trigger the formation of tables. And one more thing I am creating associations between tables, so do I need to form tables in callback of other table formation functions so that there will be no foreign key table not found constraint error???
